# How to backport `ObjectFactory.namedDomainObjectList(...)` to gradle (5.6.4)

Tags: gradle, groovy

Working on a gradle-plugin. And i've tried to backport the functionality from gradle 6 `ObjectFactory.namedDomainObjectList​(Class<T> elementType)` to gradle 5.6.4.

I'v tried this with no luck:

```
import org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder
import org.gradle.api.internal.CollectionCallbackActionDecorator
import org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection

def main() {
    def project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build();
    CollectionCallbackActionDecorator ccad;
    def myList = project.objects.newInstance(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.class,
                MyClass.class,
                new ListElementSource(),
                ccad);
}

static class MyClass implements Named {
    @Override
    String getName() {
        return "foobar"
    }
}
```

Exception Stack

```
org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.model.DefaultObjectFactory.newInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
```

[github: Source of gradle instantiation](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/bf64fff701e3d2033d41b891079969f1156d0cc4/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/collections/DefaultDomainObjectCollectionFactory.java#L104)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way:

```groovy
def myList = new DefaultNamedDomainObjectList(
        MyClass.class,
        new Instantiator() {
            @Override
            def <T> T newInstance(Class<? extends T> aClass, Object... objects) throws ObjectInstantiationException {
                project.objects.newInstance(aClass, objects)
            }
        },
        new DynamicPropertyNamer())
```